# словосочетание "слышать веру"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Можно ли использовать словосочетание "слышать веру"?

Comment: можно всё, если вы знаете почему и зачем. Но в нацкорпусе такого словосочетания нет, видимо потому что восприятие и вера вещи несовместимые.